# Localizing the app name on iOS x OSX

Tags: xcode, cocoa, cocoa-touch, localization

I have this app being created for iPhone, iPad and OSX.

In order to localize my app name, I have added the key "Application Has localized display name" key, like suggested by Apple, to my info.plist file.

I have added the InfoPlist.strings file and localized it to the several languages this app will support.

My problem is this: the app, a course, has to include "for Photoshop" at the end, something like "Course for Photoshop" on the OSX version but because iOS will truncate such a long file name, the name for iOS will be shorter.

My question is this:

1. can I add two InfoPlist.strings to the project? one for OSX and one for iOS?
2. I did all this and the name of the app inside Xcode Products (DerivedData/...bla) do not changes when I launch the app in other languages using the language argument. The name is always the english one. How do I force Xcode to build the .app name on products with the localized names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@1. I haven't tried it but you could create another target. Each target can have individual info.plist files. Then you compile one version for iOS another version for OSX as I presume you have to do anyway.

@2. Have you tried to do a project->clean? And maybe uninstall the app and then install it again with xcode.

Comment: 1. OK... 2. yes, the name is always the english one.

Comment: The localized app names are always a struggle. I just faught this myself recently and ofcourse I can't remember what exactly I did to make it work. Did you also try the opposite order. First uninstall, then clean, then install again? Sorry for asking this

Comment: Yes but I will try again. Did I mention I hate Xcode with passion? Man, this thing is horrible.

Comment: Have you added both the BundleName and BundDisplayName keys in infoplist.strings?

Comment: The keys are called CFBundleDisplayName and CFBundleName. And remember to do a project->clean everytime you change the smallest thing. I think that was why I never realized what I did to get the correct result

Comment: Suddenly remembered: when the localized names has been moved into infoplist.strings you should delete the bundlename and bundledisplayname from info.plist.